# CanCan prevent non-authorized users from going to URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I am reading through CanCan documentation and I see it's possible to grant granular resource level restrictions/authorization. My problem is slightly easier. I just need to prevent anyone who's not a particular class of user from accessing a URL. So for instance, say I have an `/admin` URL on my Rails app. I only want those users that have an `admin` role to be able to go there and redirect those who aren't to the home page, is CanCan capable of handling this type of granularity as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, not only it's possible it's CanCan's job.

Maybe you havn't read the doc in very details. Actually CanCan works on controller level. It relies on `before_filter` `authorize!` to send message to `ability` class, and then process the authorization in clean and organized fashion.

As to how to handle the rejections, you can rescue it in ApplicationController, judging from the `exceptions` CanCan brings to you

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  # Not sure the exact message but the default should be something
  # like "you need blah blah to read admin"
  if expection.message.match /admin/
    redirect_to some_path
  end
end
```